# error while trying creating azure devops pipeline using az cli from azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am getting the following error when I try to create new pipeline from a pipeline

ERROR: TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.

using the following command:

```
az pipelines create --name "xxxxx" --org "https://dev.azure.com/xxxxx/" --project "xxxx" --yaml-path "xxxxxx.yaml" --repository "xxxxxx" --branch main --repository-type tfsgit
```

do you what permission I am missing for : "Project Collection Build Service (xxxxx)" user?

thanks

I tried to add permissions of pipeline administer privilege to "Project Collection Build Service (xxxxx)"

Answer (score 1):

ops I was missing environment variable it is working now

AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)